# Implementation of 2D LinkedList

Tags: c++

I am trying to creating a two D array of linked lists (without using std). I would like to use my class based implementation of LinkedList. I want a main list of Foo nodes each Foo node to have a list of Bar nodes. However, I can't figure out how to define that in the Foo node struct

```
struct Foo {
   Foo *next;
   int fooVal;
   LinkedList *list; /// doesn't work
}

struct Bar {
   Bar *next;
   string barVal;
}

class LinkedList {
  private:
    foo *head;

  public:
   .....

}
```

Comment: Try changing the line `LinkedList *list;` to `class LinkedList *list;`, so that the compiler knows that you are referring to a class (that will be defined later).

Comment: Please note that C++ is case sensitive. The line `foo *head;` in `class LinkedList` is not referring to `struct Foo`.

Comment: My above comments do not solve the problem of `struct Foo` not referencing `struct Bar` in any way. See the answer on how to solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Bar {
   Bar *next;
   string barVal;
}

struct Foo {
   Foo *next;
   int fooVal;
   Bar *head_of_bars;
};

class LinkedList {
 private:
  Foo *head_of_foos;
};
```

Comment: I now get a memory error when trying to set the barVal to string. I have Foo *itter = list.head, itter->head_of_bars->barVal = "FooBar" but I get a memory access error.

Comment: @NathanTakemori: I suggest that you open a new question and provide a [mre] of your new problem.